# URL scheme known but want to find URL identifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, xcode5

I have two apps. App "A" has url scheme and identifier.App "B" wants to find the identifier of App "A" by using its url scheme. how it can be done.

Comment: It's not possible to get the App identifier for another app from within a separate app. URL Schemes can take params though so the way you will have to do it is 1) Open App A. 2) Get App A's Identifier. 3) Call App B's URL Scheme passing in App A's Identifier which opens App B. 4) In App B handle the params as you wish

Comment: @Popeye when we add URL type in our info.plist ... actually we add identifier and its scheme... i am talking about that identifier.... that identifier was also entered by me but i want get it by url scheme...

Comment: @Popeye is it possible to find the version of app "A"  through app "B".

Comment: You can't find anything out about App A from App B it's not possible. Apps are sandboxed so all they know about is themselves and that's it. So you can't tell App B anything about App A whether you have created bother apps or not.

Comment: The only way for App B to know anything about App A is to open App A first and pass everything you want to know about App A to App B using App B's URL Scheme and using the methods `canOpenURL:` and `openURL:`

Comment: I've just had a look through some of your other questions and you've been told before that this information isn't accessible to you from within another app. You need to be taking the hit and stop asking the same questions over and over with the question just changed in wording. You can not access other apps information from within another app even if it's your own, it's just not possible so you might as well give up now and stop wasting your time.

Comment: @Popeye Thank you so much for making my way easy. I have just read about the "sandboxing" term.There is a concept of  "Entitlements". So can we do that with entitlements ?

Comment: I don't think you understand what entitlements are. There is absolutely no way you can be inside App B and get any information about App A. The sandbox just doesn't let you. As far as App B is concerned App A doesn't exist at all. You need to forget this idea and move on it's just not possible.

Comment: @Popeye Thanks for helping me.I appreciate your co-operation and patience.